# Laravel serve file from any path on server as if it was in the public folder

Tags: php, laravel

I want to be able to serve a file, located at any path on the server's filesystem that PHP/Apache has permission to read, as if it was in Laravel's `public` folder.

Let's say I have a local directory on my server `/var/directory/` that contains two files:

- `/var/directory/abc.jpg`
- `/var/directory/xyz.jpg`

Now, how can I make these files accessible via something like:

- `https://example.com/media/abc.jpg`
- `https://example.com/media/xyz.jpg`

I think I need a controller that handles routes for `/media/{filename}`. It's fairly straight forward to then check if said file exists on disk in `/var/directory/` and read it into PHP.

So the real question is: how I read these files efficiently and then serve them as a response to a get request? The solution should be as efficient as possible so that it works for larger files (10s to 100s of MB).

Comment: For large images, better store their compressed versions on server. Speed of load also depends upon user's internet Speed. For `media/`,you can also use .htaccess to render images. If assets are going to be requested frequently, move to a new cookie free domain entirely. A good read : https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/154911/how-does-having-assets-saved-on-a-secondary-domains-reduce-the-load-time-of-th

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out by myself. I must say, the solution is embarassingly simple.

I have all files indexed in the DB, so I can make use of route model binding. If that isn't the case for you, you'd need to look up if the file exists on disk manually.

```
Route::get('/media/{file:id}', FileDownloadController::class);
```

Then, all it takes is:

```
public function __invoke(File $file)
{
    return response()->file($file->path);
}
```

Or this if a download prompt should be raised:

```
public function __invoke(File $file)
{
    return response()->download($file->path);
}
```